# Task from python mid exam, list in dictionary, dictionary in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This was the task in `Python` middle exam at my university(first course) and I could not figure it out how to complete it.

So, there was a dictionary of wagons, seat names and availability of them(P.S this dictionary was much bigger, this is just short example).

```
d =  {
        'one': [{"Seat_name" : "A1", "isTaken" : False},
             { "Seat_name" : "A2", "isTaken" : True}],
        'two': [{ "Seat_name" : "B1", "isTaken" : True},
             { "Seat_name" : "B2", "isTaken" : False}]
}
```

I had to offer the customer the wagon and the seat that was available and if the customer chose manually and the seat was taken or wagon was full, I had to offer the ones that was available. After the exam, I still could not find a way to solve it. So, any help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think there are some mistakes in how you wrote down the dictionary. 1 and 2 should both be a list of dicts right?

Comment: Please provide some example of your tries, maybe you are close to the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Also a little explanation for the numbers and general data would be helpful. What is 1? Wagon number?

Comment: i tried to access the values manually: (e.x A1 and A2) and append them in a new list so then I could write something like(if user_input in arrayList), but I could not separate them from Falses and Trues. I just tried commands like these: for keys, values in d.items() >> for i in values >> for values_two, keys_two in values.items():

Comment: 1 and 2 are wagon numbers

Comment: I've added a little more explanation to my answer, let me know if that helps you. In general, it's always a good idea to show some effort; what you tried that didn't work out. Even if you think it is kind of embarrassing ;-)

Comment: improved the grammar and python dict key values should not be integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically this requires just a bit of `dict` handling. what you could do is extract the 'available seats' part of the input dictionary. 'not avialable' is then given by exclusion. The rest is a bunch of `if` and `print` statements; I will leave the details and "prettification" to you since detailled requirements are not provided.

I took the freedom to convert your example dict to valid Python syntax and modified it a bit so we can test the behavior of the evaluation. In principle, you'd also have to check for validity of the choice, e.g. does wagon/seat exist. I skipped that for now...

```py
def check_availability(data, choice):
    # get the available seats, let each wagon be a key here as well.
    availability = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        # k: wagon no., v: dicts specifying seat/availability in the wagon
        # check if all seats are occupied in a wagon
        if not all(i['isTaken'] for i in v):
            # if seats are available, append them to availability dict:
            availability[k] = [i['Seat_name'] for i in v if not i['isTaken']]

    # short version, actually bad style since line too long...
    # availability = {k: [i['Seat_name'] for i in v if not i['isTaken']] for k, v in data.items() if not all(i['isTaken'] for i in v)}

    # now there are three options we can walk through:
    if choice['wagon'] not in availability.keys():
        print(f"wagon {choice['wagon']} is full. available are:\n{availability}")
    elif choice['seat'] not in availability[choice['wagon']]:
        print(f"seat {choice['seat']} is taken. available in wagon {choice['wagon']} are:\n{availability[choice['wagon']]}")
    else:
        print(f"seat {choice['seat']} in wagon {choice['wagon']} is available!")


# testing
d =  {1: [{"Seat_name": "A1", "isTaken": True},
          {"Seat_name": "A2", "isTaken": True}],
      2: [{"Seat_name": "B1", "isTaken": True},
          {"Seat_name": "B2", "isTaken": False},
          {"Seat_name": "B3", "isTaken": False}]}

choice = {'wagon': 1, 'seat': "A1"}
check_availability(d, choice)
# wagon 1 is full. available are:
# {2: ['B2', 'B3']}

choice = {'wagon': 2, 'seat': "B1"}
check_availability(d, choice)
# seat B1 is taken. available in wagon 2 are:
# ['B2', 'B3']

choice = {'wagon': 2, 'seat': "B2"}
check_availability(d, choice)
# seat B2 in wagon 2 is available!
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for such a late reply. I do really appreciate your help. Your code did help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a valid dictionary. For me d should be like this(correct me if i am wrong)

```
d={1: [{'Seat_name': 'A1', 'isTaken': False},
        {'Seat_name': 'A2', 'isTaken': True}],
   2: [{'Seat_name': 'B2', 'isTaken': False}]
   }
```

Create a dictionary that will store all seats_name available for each wagon

```
a=dict() 
for item in d: 
    a[item]=list() 
    for seat in d[item]: 
        if not seat.get('isTaken'): 
            a[item].append(seat['Seat_name'])
```

now if you want to check available wagon you can directly access from a dict and if value is empty in a then you can suggest some other wagon number

Answer (score 0):

⦁   Suppose that there is a list which contains the id number, mid and final marks of four students.    The program  uses a dictionary, where the key  is the ID of the student and  value is a list containing the mid and final result of  student,  like  this  { “R/1212/09”:  [ 35,  40] ,”R/1213/09”:  [ 25,  45] ,…} .
Id  Quiz (10%   Mid exam (30%)  Final exam (60%)    Total
R/1212/09   8   35  40
R/1213/09   8   25  45
R/1214/09   9   34  54

```
   A.)  Calculate the total marks of each student and append them to your original lists inside the dictionary:
```

Similar to    {“R/1212/09”: [8, 35, 40, 75], ”R/1213/09”: [8,25, 45, 65],…}
B.) Write a python program that print   top 2 students (id and total) based on total
C.)   Print the dictionary in the following format
Grade distribution
Id      quiz   mid exam       final exam               total

⦁   Write a python program count all words in word.txt longer than 18 letters print these words and the number of such words.
⦁    Explain about default and named parameter with example.
⦁    Explain the  main difference local and global variable with example
⦁   with Explain the main difference between list, tuple and dictionary example.
⦁    What is comment? Explain types of problem of comment with example.
⦁   What are computations? explain the problem solving steps with computer
⦁   What is cloning in graphics

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).